# Web Application in SharePoint Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-administration

we have one issue that AD group(everyone) has been added in SharePoint Central Admin policy for web application level due to that all users have full control to access the all site, though user has read permission.

if it remove the group from policy for web application,user cannot access the site though user has permission in site level .

I would be greatly appreciated it if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, if a AD group has no policy permission in the central administration, but it has permission for a site collection, it can access the site collection.

Comment: Group has been added in Web application level.if we remove group from there no one can access the site even though user has site permission

Comment: You could refer the following articles to configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server.

References:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/configure-sharepoint-2013-object-cache-superuser-superreader-accounts.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-object-cache-user-accounts?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Hi Emily thank you for your information ..will let you know once done this activities

Comment: If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Emily i have try to run below command
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea silentlycontinue
$was = Get-SPWebApplication
foreach ($wa in $was)
{Write-host "Web App: " $wa.url
Write-host "Super User: " $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]
Write-host "Super Reader: " $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]
Write-host " "}

above script run before your step to follow .it shows no value .still have not done your steps to set super user and super reader .since working from home as dont have permission to go office to do this.

Comment: When you configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server, if there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Emily we will let you know once done this configuration..am plan to do on next week.and also can i have your whatsp number

Comment: Public forums cannot disclose personal information. If there is any problem with this issue, you could ask in this question.

Comment: sure emily.. will let you know once done process.

Comment: Hi Emily we have done the superuser and super reader then it is working fine after remove group from webapplication policy.Thank you very much ...